# Manual Focus by using steps with Sony JSON Camera API

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I have question regarding manual focus with SONY Camera `JSON API`.

For the automation of the FocusStack feature (combining more images with different focus values into the resulting one, to achieve the best possible sharpness of the image).

I need a manual control of the focus by using `“steps” = absolute value`. 
How we can achieve this with Sony `JSON API`? We did’t find anything related to this in the SONY Camera API documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to control the camera focus in such a manual way. When it comes to focus control here is what you can do:

- Change the focus mode (Single AF/Continuous AF/Direct Manual Focus/Manual Focus)
- Set the focus coordinate
- Set Tracking focus on/off